# SQL query inserting twice

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax

I'm creating a quiz page that would ask questions and at the end will show top scores table. I'm accessing this page through Ajax to insert username and score and it's inserting it twice.

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "pswd";
    $dbname = "mydb";
    $toJsonArr = array();

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    if (isset($_GET["username"])) {
        $username = $_GET["username"];
        $score = $_GET["score"];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `fullstackQuiz` (`id`, `place`, `username`, `points`, `now`) VALUES (NULL, '0', '$username', '$score', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "1";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }

        $conn->close();

    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `fullstackQuiz` ORDER BY `fullstackQuiz`.`points` DESC LIMIT 10";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                  $toJsonArr[] = $row;
            }
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }

        echo json_encode($toJsonArr);
        $conn->close();
    }
?>
```

My Ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "sql.php",
  data: { username: "abc", score: "99" },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log("success");
  }
});
```

Every time the Ajax runs, it will create the record twice for some reason.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says [**your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You repeated `$conn->query($sql)` twice. Remove one and it will work:

```
//$result = $conn->query($sql); <== Remove this line.

if ($conn->query($sql) === true) {
    echo "1";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Also don't pass `NULL` to an auto-increment ID, just exclude it from the query. And if the `place` field is a number, then pass the value as a number without apostrophes:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `fullstackQuiz` (`place`, `username`, `points`, `now`)
        VALUES (0, '$username', '$score', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);";
```

Finally, your query is open to SQL attacks. Use a parameterized query instead.